# What is the purpose of runfiles in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to understand ["runfiles"](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/runfiles) in Bazel.

- What is the purpose of runfiles in Bazel?
- What do runfiles achieve that could not be accomplished by placing files at a predictable relative path to an executable?
- Why are there runfiles libraries for various target languages?

Answer (score 3):

There are different reasons.

- Hermetic tests: How should Bazel differentiate between random files lying around and files that are really needed/intended for a test
- Remote execution: If you use remote execution it does not help to have the files on or local development environment - you need to move them to a remote executor.
- Caching: How to cache test if the use different input files

Answer (score 1):

@Vertexwahn already gave a good answer for the purpose of runfiles, I'll just add on to this:

> Why are there runfiles libraries for various target languages?

For multiplatform support (e.g. Windows runfiles are quite different), convenience, and less boilerplate. They're not strictly necessary because you can use your language's path and I/O APIs at runtime, depending on your environment. Bazel can be quite opinionated about the runfiles layout/structure, which is why some users find it useful to use the runfiles libs' APIs instead.